Azure Analysis Service memory consumption
I have an AAS service in S9v2 tier and cleaned some of the models. Accordingly I calculate the size of remain tabular models hosted in this server over ssms>properties, totaly have 175 GB and decided to scale it down to S8v2.
However, when I check the memory consumption in Azure Portal>AAS>Metrics>"Memory Usage", memory consumption is 250 GB while not processing/refreshing the data.
I can understand that the processing may take some additional memory but 75 GB additional memory on top of 175GB seems like too much and would like to see where it comes from.
However, I can't see neither allocations of models in the portal nor details of memory consumption.
Is there a way to clean cash memory (except pause/resume) and investigate the memory consumption details?

Pause & resume server,
Parameters in AAS>Metrics


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
